# How do I get non-ascii characters from child_process.stdout?

Tags: node.js

I have a node task that spawns a child process and forwards that process' output to stdout:

```
var child = require( 'child_process' ).spawn( 'some_cmd' );
child.stdout.on( 'data', process.stdout.write.bind( process.stdout ) );
```

This works fine except that any non-ascii characters, specifically control characters for text color, don't come through.  So all my text from the child_process is white.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?  Alternatively, does anyone know how to just show `child_process` output directly without bridging the streams?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (though if anyone has an answer as to how to actually read character control data, I'd still be interested):

Calling `child_process.spawn` with `stdio: 'inherit'` passes stdout and stderr to the child process, so this issue goes away.

```
require( 'child_process' ).spawn( 'cmd', { stdio: 'inherit' } );
```